# Finding Deleted / Updated record statement from SQL Server transaction Log backup file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, database-administration

One of my production server's data was updated / deleted by someone.

I want to find out when the data was deleted or updated, and if it's updated/ deleted  then through which statement it is updated (means the query statement details like through which query it is happened).

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming**, but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Comment: If your database is using the full recovery model and you have the transaction log from the time that the data was changed, you can find some information about the transaction that made the change. See Remus Rusanu's post on reading the transaction log: http://rusanu.com/2014/03/10/how-to-read-and-interpret-the-sql-server-log/